# How can i reset anything after commit?

Tags: git

I need to commit a folder, then reset anything else to the remote state and push the commit.

If I would do

```
git commit
git reset --hard
git push
```

then the `git reset --hard` would destroy the commit, right?
how can I achieve it?

Comment: What is your end goal? Both your description and flow chart are indicating you want to make a commit that you'll immediately destroy....

Comment: i have a repo that is deployed to >10 servers. each server has a special folder in that repo that is changed by a webinterface. other servers don't touch this folder. i need a script that commits the changes from those special folders. what is the best practise to do so from server-side?

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-checkout-revet-reflog-reset/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after performing a commit, you can safely do

```
git push
```

This will only push the commits that you made. Any `unstaged` or `untracked` changes will remain locally, you don't **need** to remove them.

Suppose you really want to remove them for another reason; to remove all the `unstaged` changes (warning: those changes will be lost!) you can do:

```
git checkout -- :/
```

if you have any `untracked` changes; and you don't want them to show up, you can either

- remove those files
- put them in the `.gitignore` file.

Comment: thanks a lot. i had the repos messed up in some of the servers. after i cleaned up and resetted some stuff it now works as expected with a regular fetch => add => pull => commit => push cycle.